# Should we handle dataAccessException and jdbc exception in springboot in production?

Tags: sql, spring-boot, jpa

public UserMailDto getUserByEmail(String email) throws UserExceptionMessage {

```
    try {
        return userRepository.searchByMail(email);
    } catch (DataAccessException | JDBCConnectionException accessException) {
        com.example.user_service.config.log.Logger.errorLog("UserService", accessException.getMessage());
        throw new DataAccessExceptionMessage(Messages.ERROR_TRY_AGAIN + accessException.getMessage());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my view you should handle it, but not with a try..catch block in what seems to be your service. Why are you catching the Exception and then rethrowing you own custom Exception with a message? You will need to handle that Exception at some point in your code too. So you are not really handling it here.
It looks like you are building a web app, so I would recommend that you handle your Exceptions in one central place in a `@ControllerAdvice` class. [You can read about it here.](https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring#controlleradvice) This way you can really handle the Exception, by returning a corresponding status code to the user. 503 in your case.

Comment: Ya I had already built  ControllerAdvice class